# How to commit into TortoiseSVN using cruise control config file

Tags: tortoisesvn

> hi all,
>
> can any one tell how to commit into
>   tortoisesvn using cruise control
>   config file. I am getting an error
>   "C:*****\Documentation\trunk\dotnet\svn"
>   is not executable or it may not exist.
>
> here's the config part...

```
<workingDirectory>C:\*****\Documentation\trunk\dotnet\</workingDirectory>
     <category>Individual Solutions</category>
     <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds>          
     <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>******* svn url *********</trunkUrl>
       <username> unname </username>
       <password> pwd </password>
       <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
     </sourcecontrol>

     <tasks>

       <exec>
         <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
         <buildTimeoutSeconds>1200</buildTimeoutSeconds>
         <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>          
       </exec>

       <exec>
         <executable>iisreset</executable>
         <buildArgs>/stop</buildArgs>
       </exec>       

       <exec>
          <executable>c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"C:\*****\Documentation\trunk\dotnet\"</executable>          
         <buildTimeoutSeconds>1200</buildTimeoutSeconds>
         <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
         <description>checkin shared content...</description>
       </exec>

       <exec>
         <executable>iisreset</executable>
         <buildArgs>/start</buildArgs>
       </exec>       
     </tasks>     
</project>
```

> Thank you all,

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things:

1. You want to pass the command-line arguments to in the `<buildArgs>` element, not as part of the `<executable>` element (like you've done for the "issreset" command, for example).
2. Why are you checking stuff in after every build? The way you seem to have things set up here, it's just going to go into an infinite loop, building then checking in and building again (because it detected a new check-in). Generally, you don't check build outputs into your repository.